# Filter with xdg-mime and find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to list audiofiles that were created/modified in a 30 day interval.
To list the files I used this :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -30 -printf "%f\n"
```

This command is giving me the name of the files that were created within 30 days but I want to filter this list using this :

```
xdg-mime query filetype go.mp3
```

The result of this command is

```
audio/mpeg
```

In the end, I want to print the name of the audio files using find when the result of the xdg-mime command on these files contains "audio" but I don't see how to mix the two commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include your condition into `find` like

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -30 \
     -exec bash -c 'xdg-mime query filetype "{}" | grep -q audio' \;\
     -printf "%f\n"
```